# Where are the hooks in RSpec for mocking various aspects of a request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.2, integration-testing, rspec-rails

I am very new to RSpec. I'm writing a test for a REST API that we're making in Rails. The API consists of one action with the following specification for the requests it will accept:

> A request will only be accepted if:
>
> - It is made using HTTPS
> - It is sent as a POST request
> - It is sent with the following parameters: value_name, value, item_id
>
> For example, a valid request is:

```
POST /new_api/action HTTPS/1.0
snip
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 52

value_name=Contract+Id&value=abcdef123456&item_id=38
```

The specification states that if a request is sent that meets these requirements, the server will respond with a `200` code. If a request is sent that doesn't meet these requirements, the server will respond with a `400` code.

With these requirements, I would like to write RSpec tests that ensure the action responds with the proper code depending on whether the request:

- is sent using HTTP/SSL
- is sent using `POST` or a different request type
- has the correct parameters

This is psuedo-Ruby for one of the tests I want to write:

```
describe 'New REST API' do
  it 'should accept valid requests'
    request = mock a request that
      uses HTTPS
      has these parameters: {:value_name => "name",\
        :value => 1, :item_id => 2}
    end

    post name_of_new_action using request
    response.status.should be(200)
  end
end
```

What are the proper hooks in RSpec to:

1. Mock a request
2. Indicate that the request should or should not be "sent" over HTTPS/SSL
3. Indicate which parameters should be sent to the server
4. Simulate sending the request via POST
5. Check what the server's response code is

We're using Rails 3.2.13 and Ruby 1.8.7 (this is an older app that we're maintaining). Our Gemfile has

```
gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 2.11.0'
gem 'guard-rspec', '~> 1.2.1'
gem 'capybara', '~> 1.1.2'
gem 'database_cleaner', '~> 1.1.1'
gem 'factory_girl_rails', '~> 1.7.0
```

Comment: If I poked around long enough, I would probably find answers to all of these questions. Again, though, I'm very new to RSpec, and I'm having a hard time finding articles that both answer my questions and are introductory enough for me to grok what they're saying. If don't give me a direct answer but point me in the direction of resources that can help me out, I would also appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you need is native in Rails integration test lib, even no need Rspec.

- It is made using HTTPS

  ```
  get test_path, nil, {'HTTPS'=>'on'}
  ```
- It is sent as a POST request

  ```
  post test_path, {foo: 'bar', fff: 'bbb'}
  ```
- It is sent with the following parameters: value_name, value, item_id, in HTTPS.

  ```
  post test_path, {value_name: 'abc', value: 'foo', item_id: 'bar'}, {'HTTPS'=>'on'}
  ```

Check response need Rspec

```
expect(response).to be_success
expect(response.status).to eq(200)
expect(response.body).to match(/some string in body/)
```

Comment: Our team is already using RSpec for its other tests, which is why I want to use it.  Would the same test in RSpec use the same code except for the assertions at the end?

Comment: @Kevin, the former part is part of Rails which can be used in Rspec for testing controllers without any problem. http://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Integration/RequestHelpers/get The later part belongs to Rspec. You may not be familiar with `expect`, it's just another expectation style, similar to `should`. In most cases they can be used interchangeably.

Comment: That makes sense. I'll try your answer once I'm back in the office and accept it when I've gotten it to work =)